# How to add onClick method to ImageView inside a grid layout?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a tic-tac-toe like game which contains some circular balls that are dropped when user taps on the rooms where he wants to deploy. I have added those images inside a grid layout but I'm not able to run a dedicated method when a user taps on them. I have assigned the method to onclick property of imageview but the java code isn't being executed.

EDIT: I tried to log something when the grid layout was click and it was logged. So the conclusion is that the grid layout is blocking the click to be registered to the imageview.

Here's my Java code:

```
public void dropIn(View view) {
    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
    counter.setTranslationY(1000f);
    counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
    counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
}
```

This is the XML code for the image view:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />
```

Here is the XML code for the grid:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:rowCount="3">
```

Comment: How have you determined that the "java code isn't being executed"? Have you set a breakpoint there, or done some logging in that method? Or are you just going by the lack of response?

Comment: I checked the logcat and also tried logging some info.

Comment: Well, there's really only two possibilities for that setup, assuming you're looking at the right stuff – either that code is running, but just not having the desired effect, or it crashes. Are you sure you're not missing your logs? What happens if you set a breakpoint on the first line in that method?

Comment: I am 100% sure that the code is not executed. I think the grid layout is stopping the click to be registered to the imageview.

Comment: Well, `GridLayout` itself isn't going to stop clicks, but there is apparently something wrong with the setup that's not shown here. Are you sure something else isn't covering the `GridLayout`?

Comment: Yes I guess I'm sure. Do you need to see more of the code or setup?

Comment: At this point, we'll probably need to see a [mcve], 'cause you've ruled out the likely issues. Real quick, though, does it work if you set an `OnClickListener` on one of them in code, just to test?

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: Take the code that Acemond has in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55969412), and put it in `onCreate()`, after the `setContentView()` call.

Comment: I tried to log something when the grid layout was click and it was logged. So the conclusion is that the grid layout is blocking the click to be registered to the imageview.

Comment: Nah, as I mentioned, `GridLayout` isn't going to interfere with clicks itself, by default. I just put what you've posted here into a test project, only adjusting the margins for my screen size, and the clicks happen just as expected.

Comment: Can you give me the link for the proect so that I can see what was wrong?

Comment: OR check my project here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16sdizjapopviqqQKLmcBNquk9wkNgyGg?usp=sharing and check what's wrong.

Comment: It's basically just what you've got here, with minor adjustments for margins and visibility: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a2tBVwKmAEVZSkRZW5-9c7p_dUuIBH_3/view?usp=drivesdk. I'll have a look at yours here in a minute.

Comment: The main thing I see in your project is that the `ImageView`s are all basically invisible at the start, since they have no image or background. If you're going by that `board` drawable you've set as the `GridLayout`'s background to determine where the `ImageView`s are, that's not a good idea, since those aren't going to line up exactly as you have them in editor on devices of different sizes and densities. I'd suggest you set a background color on them in the XML, like I've done in my test, so you know that you're clicking in the rights spots during your tests.

Comment: I have already tried by adding images in my `ImageVIew`s but it again didn't work. I am 100% sure that I tapped on right places right where `ImageView`s are. Are you sure that it worked? I tried using your code but the result was exactly same.

Comment: I wouldn't have taken the time to copy and post it to Drive if it didn't work for me. Here's the debug apk, if you want it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UjtrE1Qvlab27TiDYnISKVie96IvFxbm/view?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: Can you please upload the project folder?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1-DYCnyOeNmh26J0-xI2IVtsrzE9mYQkM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it programmatically instead of assigning the method via XML view.

In first place you need to create a new ImageView and then get the view rendered with findViewById() method. Then, assign the onClickListener with the "dropIn" logic:

```
ImageView counter = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
counter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter.setTranslationY(1000f);
        counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Where should I add that code?
EDIT: I have to add that method to 9 ImageViews. How do I do that?

Comment: For each imageview, you must set the onClickListener. Then, inside onClick method, call a new function called "clickView(v)" passing "v" view as parameter. Declare the "clickView" function with the translations and all other stuff.